# Symlink on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have created a repo on GitHub and push an IOS framework (which use some symlink)  into it.

Git seem to destroy/refactor symlinks accordings to some discussions I found.

But I found this repo that have symlink: https://github.com/appfeel/google-iosadmobads/tree/master/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework

Here is a screenshot of my repo:
[image]

You can see "Headers" file, which is a symlink look like a basic file...

But on the other repo I have:
[image]

The icon really look like a symlink :)

My question(s) is/are: How can I do this? Git option? Commit on UNIX OS? (I'm on Windows right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used a Ubuntu Virtual Machine to create Symlinks and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

From `git help config`

> core.symlinks
>              If false, symbolic links are checked out as small plain files that contain the link text.  git-update-index(1) and git-add(1)
>   will not change the recorded type to regular file. Useful on
>   filesystems
>              like FAT that do not support symbolic links.
>
> The default is true, except git-clone(1) or git-init(1) will probe and set core.symlinks false if appropriate when the
>   repository is created.

This means that to maintain windows compatibility, you can set this option to false so that your symlinks are stored as plain text files, such as the one on the github repository.

Comment: Thks for your reply.
According to my local git config file symlink is already set to false.

[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
 hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly

Comment: Solved by using a virtual machine :)